# Flash CS6 AS3 test movie in browser not working

Tags: actionscript-3, browser, flash

I have a button to link URL using Flahs CS6 AS3.
When I test it in Flash Professional,(Cntl+Enter) it worked, but when I test in Browser (F12) the button is not working.
also when I open swf file it self, it is not working as well.
Only works when it export from Fla file (using Cntl+Enter), but not opening acutal swf file from the folder)

the code is this - and I think this one is ok, because it working when exported (Cntl+Enter)

```
function gotoAuthorPage(event:MouseEvent):void

 { 
  var targetURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.google.com/"); 
  navigateToURL(targetURL,"_self"); 
} 

  my_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoAuthorPage);
```

Does anybody know why this happening and how can I make it work in browser, and swf file...
please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> from Flash, your SWF is executing in projector.

Make sure your publish settings enable network access from *"local playback security"*:

[image: publish-settings]

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked in swf file now. but not still in browser... :( when I press F12... but that's ok I will find out how I can do from here. Thanks again!

Comment: Make sure the SWF isn't cached in your browser.  Also, try testing it from a web server.