# AS3 URLRequest not working in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, urlrequest

My URL request is working perfectly in Flash Pro, but when I test it in the Browser, the image doesn't work at all. It doesn't load. Is there a Publish Setting I need to be using or something?

Please help, it's pretty frustrating. [Here's](http://nooodisaster.deviantart.com/art/Beyonce-SlidingPuzzle-Flash-Diary-Day-10-430670177) what it looks like when it's in the browser.

Relevant code:

```
    public function startSlidingPuzzle() {
        // blank spot is the bottom right
        blankPoint = new Point(numPiecesHoriz-1,numPiecesVert-1);

        // load the bitmap
        loadBitmap("http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/030/d/7/slidingimage_by_nooodisaster-d74et6t.jpg");
    }

    // get the bitmap from an external source
    public function loadBitmap(bitmapFile:String) {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingDone);
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(bitmapFile);
        loader.load(request);
    }

    // bitmap done loading, cut into pieces
    public function loadingDone(event:Event):void {
        // create new image to hold loaded bitmap
        var image:Bitmap = Bitmap(event.target.loader.content);
        pieceWidth = image.width/numPiecesHoriz;
        pieceHeight = image.height/numPiecesVert;

        trace(numPiecesHoriz)

        // cut into puzzle pieces
        makePuzzlePieces(image.bitmapData);

        // shuffle them
        shufflePuzzlePieces();
    }
```

Comment: Flash can't load data from a web server other than the one it is hosted on unless a valid crossdomain policy is in place on the target server. Read more :- http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/cross_domain_policy.html

Comment: this answer helped me alot, same issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131638/flash-cs6-as3-test-movie-in-browser-not-working

Answer (score 1):

You have a security error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2122: Security sandbox violation: Loader.content: http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/030/e/e/beyonce_slidingpuzzle___flash_diary_day_10_by_nooodisaster-d74er8h.swf cannot access https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls9QI.jpg. A policy file is required, but the checkPolicyFile flag was not set when this media was loaded.
at flash.display::Loader/get content()
at SlidingPuzzle/loadingDone()
```

Try adding a security context:

```
public function loadBitmap(bitmapFile:String)
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingDone);

    var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
    context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
    context.checkPolicyFile = true;

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( bitmapFile );
    loader.load( request, context );
}
```

If that doesn't fix it you'll need to add a crossdomain.xml to the server hosting the images you are requesting.  Why not save the images locally and deploy them in the same scope as your build?

[1]: